# How to avoid duplicate types with xsd schema definitions?

Tags: java, xml, xsd, jaxb

I got a customer that imports XML data that respect several standards (about 100 XSDs files).

Of course, I'm using Java and Jaxb to generate classes and it is really a pleasure (as ever).

I've made some Jaxb bindings to rename tags, attributes, etc... and it covers most of my uses.

**BUT** some data structures in XSD are duplicated.

The only thing I see is to extract some XSD structures and put them into a common XSD.

So here are my steps:

1. extract common data structures in one or several XSD files in a dedicated namespace (to be shared easily) and import them with XSD `import` feature
2. when data structures are almost the same, use the XSD inheritance feature i.e. `extension`.
3. generate my new model with jaxb xjc tool
4. prefix my new extracted data structures with correct namespace prefix with XML files to import (XSLT preprocessing to add missing new prefixes)

Because my customer won't change its XML files, I have to perform step 4.

The proper way indeed would be to modify the standard XSD but this is not possible in my case (can take months or years or never taken into account by XSD analysis team...)

The main drawbacks are:

- XSD are modified so in case of update it can take a long time to "replay" modifications
- some preprocessing on XML is needed

The main advantage is that you don't have to duplicate your code... And in my case, it really doubles the effort (at least).

Now my question is **has someone a better way to handle this use case?**.

Thank you all in advance.

Comment: I'm against changing the source message on the route to fit your requirements in such way. the only correct way is to have something in between like a broker/hub/esb that has a source and destination contract and a mapping specification. The proper solution depends on the structure of the xml schema's. are they having a namespace and is it unique per file or general for all? Is there versioning on the xml schema's? depending on that a solution direction can be chosen.

Comment: Hi @martijn, to answer your questions:

* no versioning...
* one namespace for the few files they are managing and of course several others namespaces for xsd they are importing.


I totally agree with you. Altering the xsd source is totally crappy. That's why, since my initial request, I'm processing it in XSL to transform it (i.e. extracting redundant structures or classes) and to fit my needs.
The risk remains if the input format changes but "normally" should not be too frequent (I hope). Thank you a lot for your comment.